# Using Visual Studio Team Services on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure-devops

We have web application developed in visual studio 2015. We are using Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2.

So far only single developer was handling the development so source code was in one machine only. Now we are thinking of expanding the team. So If we go for online

Visual Studio Team Services

which is free for 5 users (I guess so), do we need to upload all source code to Azure?

How about the security about the source code?

Is there any possibility of leaking the code or any issues regarding security?

Any one has used this?

Comment: This question is off-topic, as it's not a programming question. "Has anyone used this?" - not sure what you're expecting aside from opinions. And asking if there is any possibility of code leak? You should be able to find out everything you need in Microsoft's [Trust Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/default.aspx) - aside from that, there's simply no way to answer your questions, as they are all speculative (aside from pricing, which is clearly documented).

Comment: Also - Not sure why you tagged this as "Azure" - VSTS is a separate service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) is free for up to five users, and includes [unlimited private Git repositories](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/git/free-private-git-repo/).

Your repositories are private, and you can manage who can view and edit your repositories.  The VSTS team is aggressively committed to security.  [Microsoft's own source code is managed in Visual Studio Team Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/05/24/the-largest-git-repo-on-the-planet/), and stored in Azure.

But if you are truly worried about bringing your source code outside of your firewall, then you can use [Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/) instead.  This is the on-premises version of Visual Studio Team Services, with the same functionality.  It's also free for up to five users, but you will need to configure and manage it yourself.

Comment: Best not to answer these types of questions - it's not programming-related. And then... "has any one used this?" - this is just calling for opinions. Pricing is documented on the product page. Best to just close-vote.

Comment: I don't agree, "software tools commonly used by programmers" is explicitly _on topic_.  "Is VSTS secure?" seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: (However, I do agree that the question could be improved with editing.)